# Небольшая социальная сеть локального применения

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, вопрос достаточно избитый, но нуждаюсь в помощи, необходимо создать простую социальную сеть на java, с пользованием Spring, не хотелось бы изобретать велосипеды, надеюсь вы с пониманием отнесётесь и посоветуете хорошие статьи, книги, открытые исходники подобных проектов и т.д.

Comment: http://www.spring-source.ru/docs_simple.php учебник.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm - работа с БД.
Чем собирается проект и зачем так: https://habrahabr.ru/post/78252/ (речь о Maven).

Аннотации - это важно! (`@RequestMapping, @PathVariable, @RequestParam`)

Передача данных на форму из контроллера: model.addAttribute("ключ", значение).

Первое, что в голову приходит.

Comment: спасибо, опыт написания простейших web приложений на java есть, сборки: maven, gradle, работа с базами: jdbc и hibernate, spring осваиваю, вот и хотел попрактиковаться в такого рода проектах, как написание простейшей соц сети, интересны алгоритмы организации взаимоотношений пользователей а так же система сообщений между пользователями, возможность авторизации через другие соц сети, это как базовый набор.

Comment: Алгоритмы взаимодействия пользователей + авторизация через другие СС ` => ` структура БД + кэширование данных (noSQL БД?). Думаю, в первую очередь нужно погуглить на тему "как крупные СС хранят данные".

Comment: java насколько известно, вообще мертвый язык. Для создания соцсети есть куда более надежные, точенее работающие способы. Самый лучший это node.js не будет просблем с решением. java умер.

Comment: @Amir java вообще ни разу не мертвый язык. По поводу node.js - не сказал бы, что js/node.js - более надежен, и как-то "точнее работающий", особенно с "интересным" подходом javascript к типизации.